# Create Folder and Optional SubFolder based on file name using batch file

Tags: batch-file

There are two areas where I need some guidance and not sure if this is possible or not. Please note that below code is working as intended.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sourcedir=C:\FILETEST"
pushd %sourcedir%
for /f "tokens=1,2*delims=-" %%a in (
 'dir /b /a-d *-*--*.*'
 ) do if "%%c" neq "" (  
 md "%%a-%%b"
 move "%%a-%%b--%%c" ".\%%a-%%b\"
)
popd
goto :eof
```

The above code caters for file names have a "-" and "--", for example filename "UK-London--filename.doc" would create a folder "UK-London" and put the file there.

However, there are also other filenames that are more detailed, for example filename "EU-UK--London-Camden--filename.doc". The below script works for this example and will create a folder for "EU-UK", then a subfolder "London-Camden" and put the file there:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "sourcedir=c:\FILETEST"
pushd %sourcedir%
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4*delims=-" %%a in (
 'dir /b /a-d *-*--*-*--*.*'
 ) do if "%%e" neq "" (  
 md "%%a-%%b"
 md "%%a-%%b/%%c-%%d"
 move "%%a-%%b--%%c-%%d--%%e" ".\%%a-%%b\%%c-%%d\"
)
popd
goto :eof
```

The first issue that I am having is that I need to use both scripts to go through all files and it sometimes is a hit and miss. Is there a way to combine the two scripts with an "if exist" statement?

The second issue and more of a question is currently the delims is set to "-", can I add another delims e.g. "_"?

Thank you and please let me know if any questions.

Panos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.doc" '
 ) DO (
 SET "filename=%%~na"
 FOR  /f "tokens=1-3delims=:" %%m IN ("!filename:--=:!") DO (
  IF "%%o"=="" (
   MD "%destdir%\%%m" 2>NUL
   ECHO move "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%m\"
  ) ELSE (
   MD "%destdir%\%%m\%%n" 2>NUL
   ECHO move "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%m\%%n\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I'm assuming all of your `.doc` files fit the masks provided.

The `dir` command produces a list of all of the `.doc` files (obviously, provide a different mask if required). Each name is then assigned to `%%a` and the name part only to `filename`.

Using `delayedexpansion`, convert each `--` to `:` (a character that can't exist in a filename) and use the `delims=:` to tokenise to `%%m..%%o`. Then check whether the third token (and hence second level) exists and perform the appropriate create and move.

Note that `md one\two` will create `one` if it doesn't already exist. The `2>nul` suppresses complaints that the directory already exists.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

As for the `delims` issue, any character between the `=` and `"` is defined as a delimiter; all ranking equally. The line will be interpreted as *delims* token1 *delims* token2 ... where the *delims* string is a sequence of (any of (any of the delimiters))

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you could use a more general approach: whatever the filename happens to be, change all occurrences of `"--"` to `"\"` so that you create a pathname (full file spec such as `C:\path\to\name.ext`). Then extract the parent directory from the pathname, and move the file accordingly.

Something like this (not tested):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*) do (
    set "pathname=%%a"
    set "pathname=!pathname:--=\!"
    for %%b in ("!pathname!") do set "parent=%%~dpb"
    md !parent!
    move "%%a" "!pathname!"
)
```